# MySQL Attributes Search (Strict)

Tags: mysql, sql

I got the following query :

```
SELECT      SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS u.unit_id, u.unit_serial_full, u.unit_status, u.contract_id, u.warehouse_id,
            m.model_name,
            c.contract_name,
            t.transfer_id,
            w.warehouse_name_full
FROM        units AS u
LEFT JOIN   models AS m ON m.model_id = u.model_id
LEFT JOIN   contracts AS c ON c.contract_id = u.contract_id
LEFT JOIN   transfers AS t ON t.transfer_id = u.transfer_id
LEFT JOIN   warehouses AS w ON w.warehouse_id = u.warehouse_id
LEFT JOIN   units_attributes AS ua ON ua.unit_id = u.unit_id
WHERE       1
        AND u.company_id = :company_id
        AND (
                (
                    u.model_id = "4"
                AND (
                        ua.attribute_id = :attribute_id_0 AND attribute_default = :attribute_value_0
                    )
                AND (
                        ua.attribute_id = :attribute_id_1 AND attribute_default = :attribute_value_1
                    )
                )
            )
```

If I search with 2 or more attributes, It give no result but if I have only 1 attribute, the query work as expected. Any ideas ?

The search must be strict. Not with wildcard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ua.attribute_id can't be two values at once

```
(
    ua.attribute_id = :attribute_id_0 AND attribute_default = :attribute_value_0
)
AND (
    ua.attribute_id = :attribute_id_1 AND attribute_default = :attribute_value_1
)
```

Comment: That I figured out, the question is how can it be ?

Comment: Well, you could use an OR condition

Comment: The OR will allow 1 unit to have 1 value and the other unit to have a value but they won't share 2, 3 or 4 similar attribute value.

Comment: OK. If you need to have units_attributes records for each value that you put in, you could add another left outer join for units_attributes

Comment: So one join per attribute ?

Comment: yeah. am trying to think of a way that you could use the 'in' operator as this solution is definitely not scalable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25237/discussion-between-chetter-hummin-and-david-belanger)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS u.unit_id, u.unit_serial_full, u.unit_status, u.contract_id, u.warehouse_id, m.model_name, c.contract_name, t.transfer_id, w.warehouse_name_full
FROM        units AS u
LEFT JOIN   models AS m ON m.model_id = u.model_id
LEFT JOIN   contracts AS c ON c.contract_id = u.contract_id
LEFT JOIN   transfers AS t ON t.transfer_id = u.transfer_id
LEFT JOIN   warehouses AS w ON w.warehouse_id = u.warehouse_id
LEFT JOIN   units_attributes AS ua ON ua.unit_id = u.unit_id
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND u.company_id = :company_id
    AND u.model_id = "4"
    AND ua.attribute_id IN (:attribute_id_0, :attribute_id_1)
    AND attribute_default IN (:attribute_value_0, :attribute_value_1)
```

Comment: This give the same result as a OR

Answer (score 0):

A column cannot simultaneously have two different values.  Therefore a filter such as `ua.attribute_id = :foo AND ua.attribute_id = :bar` results in an `Impossible WHERE` clause.

The best solution is usually to *group* your results and filter the resulting groups for only those that contain records satisfying your criteria, i.e. using the `HAVING` clause:

```
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
HAVING   SUM(ua.attribute_id = :foo) AND SUM(ua.attribute_id = :bar)
```

Comment: Do you have an example with the `HAVING` clause ? Thanks. I'd filter using PHP but the problem is I don't want to pull all attributes for each unit.

Comment: @DavidBélanger: I added an example... but since I don't know the columns on which you should be grouping, it's difficult to give an exact answer.  At worst, I suppose you could group on every column in the select list.

Comment: I'll try to figure it out myself. Thanks for the example. For reference, attribute_id is the ID dans attribute_default is the value to look for.

Comment: @DavidBélanger: Then you'd probably want something like `HAVING SUM(ua.attribute_id = :attribute_id_0 AND attribute_default = :attribute_value_0) AND SUM(ua.attribute_id = :attribute_id_1 AND attribute_default = :attribute_value_1)`.